# Proof verification of god existence theorem

Tags: logic, theology, truth, modal-logic

NB:
My question was closed on math stack exchange. They advised me to post it here, but due to the lack of LaTeX formatting, I had to upload it as images. Apologies for that.

I am a first year student in undergrad, non-philosophy. The proof will lack academic rigour, but this is intended more to organise my intuitions, not to make an actually valid proof. No intentions to attack religious people or drag a discussion. I need some feedback on how to improve my logics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, I'm going to be brutally honest here. Truth and existence are not the same thing. Your deflationary theory of truth is not deflationary. Your mention of an ordered triple (time,space,logic) makes no sense. You seem to be suggesting that  the set {T,F} is a subset of the empty set which is nonsense. That's as far as I got before I gave up. If you actually have a coherent theory in mind, it is well-hidden, and in any case it would not be appropriate for a question on this forum.

Comment: If you are trying to argue that a deity that is capable of doing contradictory things does not exist then why not just say so? Your formalism is not only really bad but quite pointless. It is not difficult to understand that the existence of an irresistible spear and an impenetrable shield is contradictory. There are several possible responses as to whether this has any consequences for theism.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Could you please expand a bit more on the point that truth and existence are not the same thing? I'd be happy to be suggested some fields of philosophy/logic to study on for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I was able to understand, since I have only basic understanding about mathematical logic, this seems to me a case of "omnipotent paradox". In question word "Almighty" was used instead of omnipotent, but they mean roughly the same thing.

The omnipotent paradox raises the question of whether an all-powerful being can create a task so difficult that it cannot complete it. It challenges the logical coherence of omnipotence and has been a topic of philosophical debate.

Various perspectives exist on the omnipotent paradox. Some argue that it reveals inherent contradictions in the concept of omnipotence, suggesting limits to what even an all-powerful being can do. Others propose that the paradox arises from a misunderstanding of omnipotence or that it tests the limits of human language and logic rather than the nature of a divine being. Theological, philosophical, and logical viewpoints contribute to diverse interpretations of this paradox.

1. **Limitation of Omnipotence:** Some argue that the omnipotent paradox reveals a logical limitation to the concept of omnipotence. They contend that if an all-powerful being can create a task it cannot perform, then true omnipotence is self-contradictory.
2. **Misunderstanding Omnipotence:** Another perspective suggests that the paradox arises from a misunderstanding of omnipotence. Proponents of this view argue that omnipotence does not imply the ability to do logically contradictory actions, and creating a self-defeating task falls into that category.
3. **Testing Language and Logic:** Some propose that the omnipotent paradox is a linguistic or logical challenge rather than a fundamental flaw in the concept of omnipotence. They argue that it exposes the limitations of human language and logic when grappling with abstract and infinite concepts.
4. **Theological Interpretations:** Theological perspectives vary, with some religious traditions asserting that divine omnipotence is not constrained by human logical frameworks. Others may interpret the paradox as a tool to encourage deeper contemplation about the nature of God and the limitations of human understanding.

These perspectives collectively reflect the diverse ways in which philosophers, theologians, and thinkers approach and attempt to resolve the omnipotent paradox.

Now afterwards it's work of mathematics to make relevant modifications in proof as per these perspectives.